Foreign key not showing in database diagram or table SSMS
I have an application that was created in Microsoft Visual Studio Lightswitch with a SQL backend.  I am now recreating the app in Powerapps and want to migrate the database to Dataverse. However, I've hit an issue with one of the relationships between the tables.
I have 2 tables, Stocks and OrderDetails which are related many to 1.
However, when I look at either table in SSMS I cannot see the foreign key reference column in either table.
The relationship is showing in the Keys on the table.
enter image description here
The database diagram shows this:
enter image description here
The application built on this database is able to use the relationship so it is working somehow.
Any ideas how I can get the tables to actually show the related ID so that I can export to Dataverse?
Many thanks
All other tables in the database are showing the relationships
Script for the Order Details table below
enter code here
USE [BCG_Maintenance]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[OrderDetails]    Script Date: 03/05/2024 15:46:06 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetails](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_OrderDetails_Id]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [RowVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_OrderDetails_Quantity]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [StaticSellingPrice] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_OrderDetails_StaticSellingPrice]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [DiscountPercent] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [StaticAppOrderItem] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [OrderDetails_OrderHeaders] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_OrderDetails_OrderDetails_OrderHeaders]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetails]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [OrderDetail_OrderHeaders] FOREIGN KEY([OrderDetails_OrderHeaders])
REFERENCES [dbo].[OrderHeaders] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [OrderDetail_OrderHeaders]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetails]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [OrderDetail_Stock] FOREIGN KEY([Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Stocks] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [OrderDetail_Stock]
GO

Script for the Stocks table below:
USE [BCG_Maintenance]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Stocks]    Script Date: 03/05/2024 15:59:57 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stocks](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RowVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [CustomStockID] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [StockName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Stocks_StockName]  DEFAULT (''),
    [SerialNumber] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Licence] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [DateReceived] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Stocks_DateReceived]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [BCGOrderNo] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BCGInvoiceNo] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Location] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SellingPrice] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Stocks_SellingPrice]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [UnitPrice] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [ContractLineDiscountPercent] [decimal](18, 9) NULL,
    [BCGID] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Stock_Model] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Stocks_Stock_Model]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [Stock_Contract] [int] NULL,
    [Stock_NextNums] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Stocks_Stock_NextNums]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [Stock_DeliveryNotes] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Stocks] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Stocks]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Stock_Contract] FOREIGN KEY([Stock_Contract])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Contracts] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Stocks] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Stock_Contract]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Stocks]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Stock_DeliveryNotes] FOREIGN KEY([Stock_DeliveryNotes])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DeliveryNotesSet] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Stocks] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Stock_DeliveryNotes]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Stocks]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Stock_NextNums] FOREIGN KEY([Stock_NextNums])
REFERENCES [dbo].[NextNumsSet] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Stocks] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Stock_NextNums]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Stocks]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Stock_Products] FOREIGN KEY([Stock_Model])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Products] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Stocks] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Stock_Products]
GO


It would be better route to post what is generated when you script out the table in SSMS as opposed to linked images.

However, when I look at either table in SSMS I cannot see the foreign key reference column in either table - what do you mean by not being able to "see" foreign keys?

@topsail the foreign key is not displayed on either side of the relationship.  I would expect to see a field called OrderDetails_Stock in the Order details table and a field called Stock_OrderDetails in the Stocks table.

Sorry I just don't know what you mean by "displayed". I don't look at pictures to see if I have foreign keys. I look at the table definitions. What are you literally "looking at" when you are checking for things being displayed? Or more to the point - don't look at displays, look at the table definition. For instance, in SSMS, you can generate a create table script to see the precise definition of your table (as SQL, not as a "picture").

@topsail - sorry I was referring to the database diagram.  I have now included scripts for both tables in the original post

the foreign key is not displayed on either side of the relationship. I would expect to see a field called OrderDetails_Stock in the Order details table and a field called Stock_OrderDetails in the Stocks table Relationships don't appears as fields in tables.

How do I export the data from the database but keeping the relationships intact? Other related tables seem to have a related field in the table - Stock_Model in the stock table for example is the related id from the model table
